# How to reuse component in DomPortalOutlet while rendering dynamic component in Angular9?

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-cdk

In my angular application, I have to render dynamic components based on different situations. So whenever a new component is attached to a **DomPortalOutlet** instance, its working fine. For different situations different components will be rendered. That is also working.
But if the same situation arrives again, I have to reuse the same component having the previous state of that component in the same portal instance. Where the target element is the same for all components. So need to render component in the same target element.

In Html,

```html
<div #target></div>
```

In component **.ts** file,

```js
@ViewChild('target', {static: true}) targetElement: ElementRef;
```

This `targetElement` is passed to a service where dynamic component rendering is handled.

In service,

```js
private portalOutlet: DomPortalOutlet;

// in constructor,

constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
) { }



public load(container: Element) {
    this.portalOutlet = new DomPortalOutlet(
      container, this.componentFactoryResolver, this.appRef, this.injector);

    const portal = new ComponentPortal(this.getComponent());
    this.portalOutlet.attachComponentPortal(portal);
}

public getComponent() {
   // returns component based on situation
}
// also handled detaching DomPortalOutlet instance on main component destroy. 
// ... other stuffs
// ...
```

This `load` method is called from the main component, where `this.targetElement.nativeElement` is passed.

For example, let's say for `Sitation A`, `DynamicComponentA` is rendered. And state and view of `DynamicComponentA` will be changed. Now, `Sitation B` occurs, so in that case `DynamicComponentB` is rendered in the same **DomPortalOutlet** instance. So far no problem. Now if `Sitation A` occurs again, then I have to render `DynamicComponentA` with the same state and view as before when it was rendered previously. I want to persist the state and view of `DynamicComponentA` if it is loaded again.

Can I achieve this? If yes, then how to do it? Or any other approach to achieve this?

Angular Version: ~9